# jQuery text shows below the active one when switching between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slide-copy col-xs-8">
    <div class="art active-art" id="art_1">
        <h1>TEXT 1</h1>
        <h2>TEXT 1</h2>
        <p>A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsumA TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum... </p>
    </div>
    <div class="art" id="art_2">
        <h1>TEXT 2</h1>
        <h2>TEXT 2</h2>
        <p>A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsumA TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum... </p>
    </div>
    <div class="art" id="art_3">
        <h1>TEXT 3</h1>
        <h2>TEXT 3</h2>
        <p>A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsumA TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum... </p>
    </div>
    <div class="art" id="art_4">
        <h1>TEXT 4</h1>
        <h2>TEXT 4</h2>
        <p>A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsumA TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum A TUTAJ OPIS ELO taki bardzo dlugi lorem ipsum... </p>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="slide-img col-xs-4">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>TEXT 1</li>
            <li>TEXT 2</li>
            <li>TEXT 3</li>
            <li>TEXT 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('li').click(function()
{
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('.active-art').fadeOut(500);

    $('#art_' + index).fadeIn(500);
    $('.active-art').removeClass('active-art');
    $('#art_' + index).addClass('active-art');     
});
```

CSS:

```
.art
{
    display: none;
}

.active-art
{
    display: inline;
}

li
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5p83c/53/
and i can't figure out why it's not working. When you click for the first time it will switch as i expect, fadeOut current text, and fadeIn clicked one. But if you try to switch for the second time, it will show new text below the active one before swap. Why is that?

Comment: Your Fiddle has some nice pictures but it looks quite different from the code you have above.

Comment: Ahh my bad, i'm so sorry. Here's the good Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5p83c/53/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because fadeOut will fade the element to transparent(for the specified duration) and than hide it. And the execution of the code after fadeOut will continue even that the animation is not finished.

In your case:
Initially, you don't have any element with `active-art` class which means that you don't really need this line(or better say you're not waiting for the execution of this line):

```
$('.active-art').fadeOut(500);
```

but, the second time, you have an element with `active-art` class, and when you call fadeOut on that element, it will take 500 milliseconds to finish the animation to transparency and only at the end it will hide the element. On the other hand, `$('#art_' + index).fadeIn(500);` will show the next element before the fadeOut finished the hiding of the element(which in your case takes 500 milliseconds).

How to solve this?

You can use the complete function of the fadeOut like this:

```
$('.active-art').fadeOut(500, function () {
     // implement the fade in functionality.
});
```

Side-note that the `display` CSS property on your `active-art` class will be overridden, because `fadeIn` will animate the opacity to 1.0 and then add(or change) the CSS `display` property to `none` and `fadeOut` will animate the opacity to 0.0 and then add(or change) the CSS `display` property to `block`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvsupt4g/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `complete` function of `fadeout()`. It now wait for fadeout to complete and than execute the `fadein` so transition will be smoother.

```
$('li').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    var lastIndex = $('.active-art');
    $('.active-art').fadeOut(500, function () {

        $('#art_' + index).fadeIn(500);
        $('.active-art').removeClass('active-art');
        $('#art_' + index).addClass('active-art');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5p83c/54/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('li').click(function()
{
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
   $('.active-art').fadeOut(500,function(){
      $('.active-art').removeClass('active-art');
      $('#art_' + index).fadeIn(500);
      $('#art_' + index).addClass('active-art');  
   }); 
});
```

insteed

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mqwayr6a/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the ID as reference. Simply

```
$('li').click(function()
{
    var index = $('li').index($(this));
    $('.art:eq('+index+')').fadeIn(500).addClass('active-art');
    $('.active-art').fadeOut(500).removeClass('active-art');
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: BTW: You also really do not need the class active-art, if you load the page with $(document).ready(function(){$('.art:eq(0)').css({display:'inline'})}); where .art:eq(0) is the first matched .art

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I missed that .active-art is useful to find the element to fade out. So my previous comment isn't correct